# API.ai / Dialogflow basic text request not working

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

```
const API_AI_TOKEN = 'my token here';
const apiAiClient = require('apiai')(API_AI_TOKEN);

const apiaiSession = apiAiClient.textRequest('hi', {sessionId: 'test'});
apiaiSession.on('response', (response) => {
const result = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
console.log(result);
});
apiaiSession.on('error', error => console.log(error));
```

I configured in Dialogflow small talk and tested, i should receive "Hey" back but i get [nothing..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi5D6.png)
I tried both client and dev token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is i'm obligated to end session with apiaiSession.end()

You're not obligated to end the session. What you're doing, it's not a session, it's a request.

Without `.end()` the request is never fully sent, so you will never get a response back.

> I tried both client and dev token

You have to use dev token.

---

Here's how the code should be:

```
const API_AI_TOKEN = 'my token here'; // You need dev token
const apiAiClient = require('apiai')(API_AI_TOKEN);

const request = apiAiClient.textRequest('hi', {sessionId: 'test'});

request.on('response', (response) => {
    const result = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
    console.log(result);
});

request.on('error', error => console.log(error));

request.end(); // This.
```

The session is managed by Dialogflow, so as long as you send the same `sessionId` for each user interaction, you'll be fine.

From the [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities):

> User entities and sessions last 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is i'm obligated to end session with apiaiSession.end()